# Which provider will be used in Angular?

Tags: angular

I tried to reorganize my structure of modules. So now I have a module `RegistryAddModule` with provider: `provide: Tree`. This provider I use in component in child component `TreeComponent` in `RegistryAddComponent`.

```
export function factory(LibraryService: LibraryService, treeStatesService: TreeStatesService) {
    return TreeFactory.createTreeRegistry(LibraryService, treeStatesService);
}

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [RegistryAddComponent],
        imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, TreeModule, MatTabsModule],
        providers: [
            TreeStatesService,
            {
                provide: Tree,
                useFactory: factory,
                deps: [LibraryService, TreeStatesService],
            },
        ],
        exports: [RegistryAddComponent],
    })
    export class RegistryAddModule {}
```

Structure modules are:

**AppModule -> RegistryModule -> RegistryAddModule -> RegistryAddComponent -> TreeComponent**

Why do I get this error in component `RegistryAddComponent`:

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RegistryAddComponent -> Tree]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RegistryAddComponent -> Tree]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for Tree!

Why `TreeComponent` can not see `Tree` provider in parent `RegistryAddModule`?

**TreeComponent code is:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tree',
    templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tree.component.scss'],
})
export class TreeComponent implements TreeActions<TreeNode> {
    constructor(public tree: Tree<TreeNode>) {
        console.log(tree);
    }
}
```

**Factory is:**

```
export function factory(LibraryService: LibraryService, treeStatesService: TreeStatesService) {
    return TreeFactory.createTreeRegistry(LibraryService, treeStatesService);
}
```

**LibraryService** is registed in root app module.
**TreeStatesService** is registed in `RegistryAddModule`

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation from angular it will take the one that you provide at x level and use it there and also will pass it to inner levels.

So considering the following module levels

**a -> b -> c -> d**

with **b** used as inner module from **a**.

If tree is provided at level **c** then it will be used for levels **c, d**

If tree is also provided at level **a** then it will be used for levels **a,b**

The resolver always starts looking at the same level and if it can not find what it needs, it goes one level higher trying to find what it needs.

**This will also work if a, b, c, d are component levels**

But as the documenation says it first considers the component hierarchy levels and if something is not found there then it will consider the module hierarchy levels

More info here [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-rules)

As to your updated question

> Why TreeComponent can not see Tree provider in parent
> RegistryAddModule?

You have declared `Tree` at `RegistryAddComponent` so it will try to fetch it from that parent component. It will not consider the module hierarchy. Check there to find where the error begins

Comment: Okay, so when I need to reuse only UI component part and provide to this component data from service, where should I provide TreeService? Should I create additional modules as TreeNewModule where import TreeModule with component declaration and also add provider as TreeService with own factrory? Is it good?

Comment: What is level , is it module?

Comment: I need to resuse UI component each time but with different service data. How to do that, should I create a module?

Comment: levels will also work for component levels. That is what reffered with ElementInjector at documentation.

Comment: If you provided service at component providers level then for each component will be created new instance of service

Comment: Yes, but in my case it does not work, could I demonstrate you using remote access?

Comment: At the same component level you can't have different instances of same service. If that's what you need then store the state at component level and not at service level

Comment: I have updated question, could you help with issue?

Comment: pLibraryService, TreeStatesService are declared at root level? Also what is your factory at RegistryAddComponent? There must be the misconfiguration

Comment: I use `TreeStatesService` only in  `RegistryAddModule`. Factory I will posted in question

Comment: check the first block of code on your question. It is the RegistryAddComponent. Remove from there the {
            provide: Tree,
            useFactory: factory,... }

Comment: I have moved from provider from `RegistryAddComponent` to the module. No effect

Comment: I am thinking that your factory does not work and returns nothing. Therefore you find your error. Check your factory code

Comment: Why returns nothing? If returns `return TreeFactory.createTreeRegistry(LibraryService, treeStatesService);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229298/discussion-between-megan-kidman-and-boug).